# Низкий поклон (к) павшим

Tags: стилистика

Нет ли ошибки в выражении: "Низкий поклон к павшим"?

Answer (score 3):

В данном выражении речевая ошибка. Предлог "к" здесь неуместен. Правильно: *низкий поклон павшим*. Предлог "к" употребляется только в выражении *"идти на (с) поклон(-ом) к кому-либо"* в значении "обратиться с унизительной просьбой".

Answer (score 1):

низкий поклон /кому?/ павшим. Дательный падеж без предлога